# How to repeatedly replace regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove dangling attributes of html element.

I use regex `re.sub(r'(<[\S]+.*\s)[^=]+[\s]', r'\1', x)` to find attributes without `=`.

```
>>> import re
>>> string_list = ['<tag valid1="o n e" valid2=two some dangling></tag>', '<tag valid1="o n e" valid2=two some dangling/>']
>>> map(lambda x: re.sub(r'(<[\S]+.*\s)[^=]+[\s]', r'\1', x), string_list)
['<tag valid1="o n e" valid2=two dangling></tag>', '<tag valid1="o n e" valid2=two dangling/>']
```

But this only removes the first. How to repeatedly remove all?

Comment: Trying to parse HTML with regexes is extremely fragile. Using an actual HTML parser is much easier and safer.

Comment: @user2357112 I would like to use `ElementTree` to parse it but it only supports xml, which does not allow dangling attributes. That is why I want to do this.

Comment: [Python comes with an HTML parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html), and projects like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) make data extraction even easier.

Comment: @user2357112 This is not available in 2.7 :(

Comment: [It's just under a different name on 2.7.](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/htmlparser.html)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, I will have a try to see if I can avoid this :)

Answer (score 1):

I choose to use `HTMLParser` to parse HTML instead of preprocessing HTML and using `ElementTree` to parse HTML as XML.

Comment: That's nice, but how do you implement your solution? It will be fine to know for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall` to tokenize the parts.

```
import re
string_list = ['<div>\n<tag valid1="o n e" valid2=two some dangling></tag>\n<tag valid1="o n e" valid2=two some dangling/>\n</div>', '<tag valid1="o n e"\n valid2=two some dangling></tag>']
for string in string_list:
    output = ''
    for pre, attrs, post in re.findall(r'([^<]*</?\w+)\b(.*?)(/?>[^<]*)', string, re.DOTALL):
        output += pre + ''.join([attr[0] for attr in re.findall(r'(\s+\w+=(?:([\'"]).*?\2|\S+))|\S+', attrs)]) + post
    print(output)
```

This outputs:

```
<div>
<tag valid1="o n e" valid2=two></tag>
<tag valid1="o n e" valid2=two/>
</div>
<tag valid1="o n e"
 valid2=two></tag>
```

Comment: `></tag>` and `/>` will become `>`

Comment: Updated again then.

Comment: What about `<div>\n<tag valid1="o n e" valid2=two some dangling></tag>\n<tag valid1="o n e" valid2=two some dangling/>\n</div>`?

Comment: And also `"o n e"` becomes `"o e"`

Comment: Updated again with `re.findall` instead.

Comment: `valid2` is missing. Anyway, thanks a lot for patience. I choose to use `HTMLParser` to reconstruct html for `ElementTree`.

Comment: Updated accordingly. I think this time it's quite perfect. ;-)

Comment: `string = '<tag valid1="o n e"\n valid2=two some dangling></tag>'`, producing `'tag valid1="o n e"\n valid2=two some dangling></tag>'`, is incorrect (missing leading `<`). Never mind. Maybe it is truly not good to manually parse HTML in text level. :)

Comment: Well how about now? A `re.DOTALL` was all that's needed to recognize a tag spanning over multiple lines. :-)